# For loop pure function jest test using expect... cannot read property

Tags: for-loop, testing, jestjs, pure-function

I am trying to make a pure function using a for loop pass a jest test/npm test in the terminal... I am getting an error that it cannot read the property of toBe...

My function:

```
const syntax = {
   for1: (a,b) => {
      for(let a=1; a<10; a++){
         for(let b=1; b<10; b++){
             return a+b;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My Test.js file: I want it to test that 1+2 does not equal 0 making this test passing for the function

```
test('FORLOOP', () => {
    expect(syntax.for1(1,2).not.toBe(0));
});
```

TypeError in terminal:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBe' of undefined
      45 | test('FORLOOP', () => {
    > 46 |     expect(syntax.for1(1+3).not.toBe(0));
         |            ^
      47 | });
```

CHANGES:

TEST FILE: (fixed brackets)

```
test('FORLOOP', () => {
    expect(syntax.for1(1,2).not.toBe(0));
});
```

```
    TypeError: _syntax.default.for1 is not a function

      55 | 
      56 | test('FORLOOP', () => {
    > 57 |     expect(syntax.for1(1+3)).not.toBe(0);
         |                   ^
      58 | });
```

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are in the wrong place. It should be:

```
expect(syntax.for1(1+3)).not.toBe(0);
```

not

```
expect(syntax.for1(1+3).not.toBe(0));
```

`.not` needs to be called on the result of `expect(...)` not on the result of `syntax.for1(1+3)`.

Comment: Thanks! I ran the test now and it says for1 is not a function, why is that?

    TypeError: _syntax.default.for1 is not a function

      55 | 
      56 | test('FORLOOP', () => {
    > 57 |     expect(syntax.for1(1+3).not.toBe(0));
         |                   ^
      58 | });

Comment: @waterMelon that error message suggests that you have not corrected the brackets. Correct them, then try again.

Comment: Please give a few more details if that doesn't work!

Comment: @waterMelon how are you exporting/importing the syntax object? Also, `for1` takes two parameters but you are calling it with one in the test?